# Choregraphe red dialog box error when running the robot

Tags: dialog, nao-robot, choregraphe

Can anybody explain to me what the problem seems to be with one of my dialog boxes. All the other dialog boxes, which were created in the same way and are on the same access level are fine, but this one keeps going red when ever I launch the robot and so it does not let me enter the topic through input.

This is the error displayed: https://prnt.sc/mhnv3s

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the whole program, but it looks like you have two dialogue boxes which both refer to the same .top file, and which are both active at the same time.

When you trigger the "start" of the dialog box, it will stay active until either a) you trigger it's "stop", or b) the whole diagram in which it is is stopped (which will happen if you "exit" it, but *not* when a sub-diagram is activated).

Another possibility is that this dialogue is flagged as being collaborative dialogue, which means it could be loaded by the system while the robot is in autonomous life, and then re-launched again by your dialogue box.